# How can I deserialize any xml element to a list via the XmlSerializer?

Tags: c#, xml, xml-serialization

I want to deserialize the following xml document:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ExtensionFileTypes xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Group>
    <Item1>value 1</Item1>
    <Item2>value 2</Item2>
    <Item3>value 3</Item3>
    [ more items ... ]
  </Group>
</ExtensionFileTypes>
```

This document should be parsed to the following c# class:

```
public class ExtensionFileTypes
{
    [XmlArrayItem("Item*")]
    public List<string> Group = new List<string>();
}
```

The wildcard in the parameter of the class attribute `[XmlArrayItem("Item*")]` demonstrates what I want to archive: pass the xml elements `<Item*>` to my c# list.

I use the XmlSerializer to deserialize the xml-document:

```
public static void ReadXML(string pFilename)
{
    XmlSerializer lXmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ExtensionFileTypes));

    lXmlSerializer.UnknownElement += new XmlElementEventHandler(XmlSerializer_UnknownNode);

    FileStream lFileStream = new FileStream(pFilename, FileMode.Open);
    ExtensionFileTypes lExtensionFileTypes = (ExtensionFileTypes)lXmlSerializer.Deserialize(lFileStream);

    var lFoo = lExtensionFileTypes; // 0 Items in Group
}
```

Problem: lFoo contains 0 `<Item*>` elements:

[image]

How can I get these elements?

Comment: Wildcards are not supported in the XmlArrayItem attribute. Check the answer I've posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, the `ElementName` cannot contain a wildcard. If the number of `Item` elements is limited, for example, only `Item1`, `Item2`, `Item3`, then you could apply the `XmlArrayItem` attribute multiple times. If the number of `Item` elements is large you could process a document in advance using `Regex` to change all `Item*` tags to `Item`:

```
string updatedXmlString = Regex.Replace(xmlString, "<(/?)Item[0-9]+>", "<$1Item>");
```

Now you can simply write:

```
public class ExtensionFileTypes
{
    [XmlArrayItem("Item")]
    public List<string> Group = new List<string>();
}
```

If you cannot apply preprocessing to the xml then you could always parse it manually or implement the [`IXmlSerializable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.ixmlserializable(v=vs.110).aspx) interface.